# Generic pattern problem in C programming language

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

I encountered a pattern problem in C. I have to print the following pattern.

```
BBBB
BAAB
BAAB
BBBB
```

I wrote the following code and it worked perfectly.

```
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    
    int i,j,n;
    printf("Enter the no for pattern:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=4;j++)
                {
                    if (i==1||i==4||j==1||j==4){
                        printf("%c",65+1);
                    }                        
                
                    else{
                        printf("%c",65);
                }        
            }
        printf("\n");            
        }        
    return 0;
}
```

Now if you can see there is a value of n which is taken from the users. And the pattern depends upon the n value from the user. Right now, the pattern is static ie it is the case when n=2 ie pattern of A & B. If the user inputs n=3, the pattern will consists of A, B & C, and the pattern will be as follows:

**when n =3**

```
CCCCCC 
CBBBBC
CBAABC
CBAABC
CBBBBC
CCCCCC
```

**when n =1**

```
AA
AA
```

Now how can we make the pattern dynamic, ie based on the user input of n, the pattern should be accordingly. How can we achieve that??

Comment: You have write a recursive fnction

Comment: On a side, you should use character literals.  For example, `'A'` instead of 65.

Comment: What values of `n` do you need to support?  `26`?

Answer (score 4):

Let's give the line numbers.

```
      CCCCCC   Row y=2
      CBBBBC   Row y=1
      CBAABC   Row y=0
      CBAABC   Row y=0
      CBBBBC   Row y=1
      CCCCCC   Row y=2
Col x=210012
```

And let's give the symbol numbers

```
A B C ...
0 1 2 ...
```

Then it becomes easy: At row y, col x, we want to print the symbol corresponding to the larger of y and x. All that's left to do is build the loops.